# Unable to add ! (opposite operator) to Source item in a QT binding

Tags: qt, binding, connection

When I am adding text to a binding in the source item column, the tutorial I am following requires me to put a ! in front of the source item. However I am simply not able to type it in as the QT ide does not allow me. Was the Qt IDE recently changed to not allow this/is there a different way to indicate the ! opposite operator in front of a source item?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit it in the forms actual code (kind of unorthodox)